# Limit a DIV to appear within another DIV of specific size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on this small project that randomly displays a div (#box) of 100px width and height. I want this div to appear ONLY in another div (#boxBorder) so it appears to be limited to a specific area on the page.

Here is the content of my HTML:

```
<h1>Test your reactions!</h1>
<p id="directions">Click the shape as fast as you can!</p>
<p id="scoreC">Click score: <span id="cScore">0</span>s</p>
<p id="scoreT">Total score: <span id="tScore">0</span>s</p>

<div id="boxBorder"></div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#boxBorder {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px black solid;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

#box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}

#directions {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

#scoreT, #scoreC {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 50px 0 0;
}

#tScore, #cScore {
    font-weight: normal;   
}

h1, #directions, #scoreT, #scoreC {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And lastly, the javascript function for random position:

```
//Get random position
function getRandomPos() {
    var pos = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 1);
    console.log("POS: " + pos + "px");
    return pos + "px";
}
```

Which I call within a timeout method:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        createdTime = Date.now();
        console.log("make box: " + createdTime);
        document.getElementById("box").style.top=getRandomPos();
        document.getElementById("box").style.left=getRandomPos();
        document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor=getRandomColor();
        document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius=getRandomShape();
        document.getElementById("box").style.display="block";
    }, rTime);
```

I'm not very skilled in positioning and I can't seem to get these two divs to align so that the #box div can recognize the size of the #boxBorder div and stay within those limits. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things wrong here:

You need the `box` div nested inside the `borderBox` div if you want to use the relative positioning.

```
<div id="boxBorder">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

---

The `randomPos` function needs to take into account the size of the box, so only multiply by 400 instead of 500.

```
function getRandomPos() {
  var pos = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400));
  return pos + "px";
}
```

---

Set the style to `inline-block`, not `block` for the `box`.

---

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` to have it repeat.

---

```js
var rTime = 1000;

function getRandomPos() {
  var pos = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400));
  console.log("POS: " + pos + "px");
  return pos + "px";
}

function getRandomColor() {
  return ['#bf616a', '#d08770', '#ebcb8b', '#a3be8c', '#96b5b4', '#8fa1b3', '#b48ead'][(Math.floor(Math.random() * 7))];
}

function randomizeBox() {
  createdTime = Date.now();
  console.log("make box: " + createdTime);
  document.getElementById("box").style.top = getRandomPos();
  document.getElementById("box").style.left = getRandomPos();
  document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
}

setInterval(randomizeBox, rTime);
```

```css
#boxBorder {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px black solid;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
#box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1 {
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#directions {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
#scoreT,
#scoreC {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px 50px 0 0;
}
#tScore,
#cScore {
  font-weight: normal;
}
h1,
#directions,
#scoreT,
#scoreC {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test your reactions!</h1>
<p id="directions">Click the shape as fast as you can!</p>
<p id="scoreC">Click score: <span id="cScore">0</span>s</p>
<p id="scoreT">Total score: <span id="tScore">0</span>s</p>

<div id="boxBorder">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post, this will definitely help!